# How to investigate which services and programs are using glibc?

Tags: security, upgrade

I'm planning to upgrade `glibc` on several servers due to `CVE-2015-7547`.

https://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.jp/2016/02/cve-2015-7547-glibc-getaddrinfo-stack.html

Before upgrading `glibc`, I would like to make a rough estimate of which services and programs are involved with `glibc` so that I won't screw things up.

Are there any good way to do this?

Comment: Everything is using glibc. Just reboot the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much every single binary on a *nix system uses it, but if you want to run some specific checks, you could do something like this:

```
$ for i in sort dig nc httpd nginx postfix tail head named awk sed; do ldd $(which $i) | grep -qw libc && echo $i; done
sort
dig
nc
httpd
nginx
postfix
tail
head
named
awk
sed
```

The output will be only the binaries which reference libc, which as you can see, on the short list I have chosen above, is everything.

Normally an upgrade like this requires a restart of all services. For a library as major as this, I normally schedule a complete reboot of the system if at all possible, but I realise that this may not be possible, and in some cases, may not be required (a restart of services is usually enough).

FYI, the above script mostly works because:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/dig | grep -w libc
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2b1158a000)
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /lib64/libc.so.6
    glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure there are *nix systems free of glibc (OpenBSD, for example), and then even some linux systems that use a not-glibc libc.

Comment: @thrig Yes, you're probably right, but I've only ever dealt with mainstream Linux distros, so I know of nothing else. :)